# Dataweave 2.0 Transform Payload

Tags: json, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have this payload

```js
{
    "COV": "EL",
    "PART_LETTER": "H",
    "EFFECTIVE_DATE": "29th June",
    "LOI": "£25",
    "ENDO_APPLIED": "Y",
    "ENDO_TITLE": "Some Title",
    "ENDO": "EELZ0001",
    "ENDO_NUM": "1",
    "ENDO": "EELZ0002",
    "ENDO_NUM": "2",
    "ENDO_TEST": "TEST"
}
```

I need to transform it into the following structure -

```js
{
    "COV": "EL",
    "PART_LETTER": "H",
    "EFFECTIVE_DATE": "29th June",
    "LOI": "£25",
    "ENDO_APPLIED": "Y",
    "ENDO_TITLE": "Some Title",
    "ENDOS": [
        {
            "ENDO": "EELZ0001",
            "ENDO_NUM": "1"
        },
        {
            "ENDO": "EELZ0002",
            "ENDO_NUM": "2",
            "ENDO_TEST": "TEST"
        }
    ]    
}
```

Basically what is happening is that I need to create an array of ENDOS based on the field "ENDO". Each time we come across the field "ENDO" we need to create a new object that contains the proceeding fields until we hit another "ENDO" field..

I have tried the following but I just cannot seem to get it to work properly.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var endorsements = [payload] filter ($.ENDO != null) map (item) -> {
    "ENDO": item."ENDO",
    "ENDO_NUM": item."ENDO_NUM",
    "ENDO_TEST": item."ENDO_TEST"
}

---
payload ++ {
    "ENDORSEMENTS": endorsements
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. try to use tripple tiks (```) for adding multiline code for better formatting

Comment: To add to @HarshankBansal comment here is the documentation for more detals on [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach.

1. Divide the entries in the payload into 2 parts. One which will contain entries that are not part of the `ENDOS` array and another with the remaining entries. I used `splitWhere from dw::core::Arrays` to do this to split the entries at first `ENDO`
2. The first part will be converted back to a normal object (using `entriesToObject` function)
3. The second part will be reduced to an Array which will collect the entries in its last element until next `ENDO` entry is encountered. (using `generateEndosArray` function)

```
%dw 2.0
import update, index from dw::util::Values
import splitWhere from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json

fun generateEndosArray(endosEntries) = 
    endosEntries reduce ((entry, endos = []) -> 
        if(entry.key ~= 'ENDO') //add new element to endos
            endos << {ENDO: entry.value}
        else // update the last element and add entry to it
            endos update index(sizeOf(endos) - 1) with {
                ($),
                (entry.key): entry.value
            }
    )

fun entriesToObject(entries) = 
    entries reduce ((entry, obj = {}) -> 
        obj ++ (entry.key): entry.value
    )

var splittedEntries = 
    entriesOf(payload) 
    splitWhere ($.key ~= "ENDO")

---
{
    (entriesToObject(splittedEntries.l)), // add entries before first "ENDO" as is
    ENDOS: generateEndosArray(splittedEntries.r) // use remaining keys to generate the ENDOS array
}
```